# Java Error: The method getMethod(String, Class<boolean>) is undefined for type Class

Tags: java, class, methods, compiler-errors, undefined

I am trying to pass a method in as a parameter to a method in another class. The method is defined in the first class and the other class's method is static. Seeing it will make it easier to understand:

#### Setup

```
public class MyClass extends ParentClass {
    public MyClass() {
        super(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                try {
                    OtherClass.responseMethod(MyClass.class.getMethod("myMethod",Boolean.class));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void myMethod(Boolean success) {
        if(success.booleanValue()) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

*When I try to build*, though, I get the following error:

#### Error

```
The method getMethod(String, Class<boolean>) is undefined for the type Class<MyClass>
```

The problem isn't that it's not finding `myMethod`, it's not finding `Class<MyClass>.getMethod` and I don't know why.

### Update

We've reworked this part of the code and are not using 'getMethod`or`getDeclaredMethod`. Since npe found a couple of problems with what I was doing plus put a lot of effort into finding the answer, I'm accepting that answer.

Comment: Use `Boolean` instead of `boolean`.

Comment: The code you posted does not compile because you are placing code (the try / OtherClass.responseMethod.... stuff) directly in the anonymous class body.

Comment: For the record, in my code I didn't forget the onClick method, just in writing it on here. It's fixed on here now. Still getting the same error.

Comment: And tell us what you are compiling it with? Because now it compiles well with Eclipse and JDK 1.6.0_26.

Comment: Really? It's failing in an ant build/compile

Comment: Really, I had to _recreate_ the missing classes though, so perhaps this is the case. Post the full code with missing classes here, or as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/), and we'll see.

Comment: The missing classes? Meaning Parent and Other?

Comment: Yep. And we still don't know what java version are you using.

Comment: OK, I think I get it. You are using Java 1.4, and there is no getMethod(String, Class...), try this: `MyClass.class.getMethod("myMethod", new Class[] {Boolean.class})` and let me know if it works, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure posting the exact code is something I can do because it's work code. We're using Java 7

Comment: You may be using 1.7, but the compilation target is 1.4. Change the code as I suggested, and see if it works.

Comment: Ok, I tried that and I still got an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update 2

The compile-time error suggests, that you are using Java 1.4 to compile the class.
Now, in Java 1.4, it was illegal to define array parameters as `Type...`, you had to define them as `Type[]`, and this is the way the `getMethod` is defined for the `Class`:

```
Method getMethod(String name, Class[] parameterTypes)
```

Because of that, you cannot use the simplified 1.5 syntax and write:

```
MyClass.class.getMethod("myMethod",boolean.class));
```

what you need to do is:

```
MyClass.class.getMethod("myMethod",new Class[] {boolean.class}));
```

### Update 1

The code you posted, does not compile because of another reason:

```
super(new ClickHandler() {

    // This is anonymous class body 
    // You cannot place code directly here. Embed it in anonymous block, 
    // or a method.

    try {
        OtherClass.responseMethod(
            MyClass.class.getMethod("myMethod",boolean.class));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

What you should do is create a `ClickHander` constructor that accepts a `Method`, like this

```
public ClickHandler(Method method) {

    try {
        OtherClass.responseMethod(method);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and then, in `MyClass` constructor invoke it like this:

```
public MyClass() {
    super(new ClickHandler(MyClass.class.getMethod("myMethod",boolean.class)));
}
```

### Original answer

More to this, from the JavaDoc of [`Class#getMethod(String, Class...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29)

> Returns a Method object that reflects the specified public member method of the class or interface represented by this Class object.

And your method is `private`, not `public`.

If you want to get access to private methods, you should rather use [`Class#getDeclaredMethod(String, Class...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) and make it accessible by calling [`setAccessible(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29).

Comment: I've tried changing my method to public and protected, neither works. That's why I said the problem isn't that it's not finding my method, it's not finding `getMethod`. I want to keep it private, so I'll probably use `getDeclaredMethod` but that's not the question I'm asking right now.

Comment: Oops, I wrote it in here incorrectly. That try/catch is actually inside the `onClick` method definition inside the new ClickHandler. My bad.

Comment: Oh god... fix the question then. And post the actual broken code, not the broken-for-stackoverflow broken code.

Comment: We've reworked this section of code and my question is no longer relevant. I won't be able to find out what my problem was, but since you put so much effort into answering, you'll get the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code doesn't compile

```
new ClickHandler() {
   // not in a method !!
        try {
            OtherClass.responseMethod(MyClass.class.getMethod("myMethod",boolean.class));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I assume ClickHandler has a method you should be defining and you need to move this code to that method. In any case you cannot put this code outside a method or initializer block.

---

From [getMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29)

> Returns a Method object that reflects the specified public member method of the class or interface represented by this Class object.

Your method is `private`, not `public`

What you can use is getDeclaredMethod.

Another problem you have is that this method requires an instance, which you don't appear to be storing.

Comment: RE: private vs public, see my comment to the other answer. RE: instance, are you saying it would rather that I say `Class<MyClass> myClass = MyClass.class;" and then call `getMethod` on that?

Comment: You can do that but getMethod is still only going to give you public methods. Try getDeclaredMethod as I suggested.

Comment: Right, I know about getDeclaredMethod, but the error isn't that the method `myMethod` is not found, it`s that `getMethod` is not defined at all. And I tried doing `Class<MyClass> myClass = MyClass.class;` and that still got the same error.

Comment: I didn't realise the problem was that the code doesn't even compile ;)

Comment: Haha, yeah, I guess I should have said that bigger. Compile-time error, not runtime.